# select RID takes forever in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I am new to Orientdb, and just downloaded the latest Mac OS version, created a new databases, and created a new class named Person, which contains a first name and a last name.

Then I created 1,000,000 fake users to test the speed. However, when I run the query

> select RID from Person offset 999999

The process rans 67.569 seconds!

Following is the screen shot:
[image]

I have 2 questions:

1) Why does it take sooooo long..

2) Why is the result "#-2:1" rather than "#11:1000000"? (11 is the index of my Person class)

---

Updated

Now I noticed I should query for pagination like

```
SELECT FROM Person WHERE @rid > #11:999998 LIMIT 2
```

But it still takes 8.224s on my Macbook Air. Is it normal?

Comment: The same query takes 0.121 on my Mac Retina... What OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: @Lvca, I downloaded the Orientdb yesterday. I think it is the latest one. BTW, I found that 'SELECT FROM #11:999998' is really fast but 'SELECT FROM Person WHERE @rid=#11:999998' takes forever, are those two different?

Comment: @Lvca, perhaps previously my Mac is busy. Now I have restarted the computer and re-run the test, the query 'SELECT FROM Person WHERE rid > #11:999998 LIMIT 2' costs 1.94s, which is better, but I think is still to slow. My Macbook Air has Core i5 CPU and 4GB DDR3 RAM, is such speed normal?

Comment: The query optimizer should recognize such query and load the RIDs without executing the query, so timings should be pretty the same between select from <rid> and select from xx where @rid = <rid>. Have you tried executing the same query multiple times? Does result changes?

Comment: @Lvca, I ran several times, the 'from <rid> = xxx' cost 0.003s, while the 'from Person where <rid> = xxx' cost on average 1.3s. Also, I found this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/dq6OewXJ3dA suggesting the former is indeed faster.

Comment: That was true in 2012, but then we've the optimizer that recognizes this case and avoid query at all. Maybe on this case doesn't do the complete job. May you open a new issue here? https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/new